# How to access Garage Band stock sounds?

Tags: macos, itunes, audio, music, garageband

I have used stock sounds from iMovie (where they are called "sound effects") and would like to browse more, for example footsteps or rain to add on a podcast. Apple [allows the use of loops and audio samples](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201808), as long as they are not repackaged as loops:

> individual audio loops may not be commercially or otherwise
> distributed on a standalone basis, nor may they be repackaged in whole
> or in part as audio samples, sound effects or music beds."
>
> So don't worry, you can make commercial music with GarageBand, you
> just can't distribute the loops as loops.

I am unable to download the Essential Sounds library for lack of disk space (I downloaded 1.1 GB of the 2.1 and the compressed download expanded to 24 GB). [This page](https://www.cultofmac.com/317116/how-to-get-all-the-awesome-extra-sounds-for-garageband-10/) mentions that Garage Band comes with 50 sounds:

> When you download GarageBand from the Mac App Store, you’ll immediately get 50 sounds, 500 loops, 1 drummer, and 2 basic lessons for guitar and piano.

But I cannot find where in the app those sounds are.

I would like to access them, e.g. browsing the stock sounds and then showing them on disk or exporting them on a track to import into my Digital Audio Workstation (which is not Garage Band).

Does Garage Band come with stock sounds? How can I access them on Garage Band for macOS Mojave 10.14.6?

Comment: By access, are you looking to launch the garage band app and use the graphical interface to play the sounds?

Comment: Yes, that's one possibility and I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

On my macOS BigSur system, the Apple Loops are located at:
`/Library/Audio/Apple Loops/Apple`

Comment: Thanks. That location does not exist on Mojave.